# php ssl error when trying to connect to xmpp ejabberd server

Tags: php, ssl, xmpp, ejabberd

i tried to connect to my xmpp server using php with this library: https://github.com/fabiang/xmpp but get this following error:

```
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/html/cobaxmpp/vendor/fabiang/xmpp/src/Stream/SocketClient.php on line 210
```

here is my code

```
<?php

    $logger = new Logger('xmpp');
    $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::DEBUG));
    $hostname       = 'im2.hprasetyou.com';
    $port           = 5222;
    $connectionType = 'tcp';
    $address        = "$connectionType://$hostname:$port";
    $username = 'tom';
    $password = 'password';
    $options = new Options($address);
    $options->setLogger($logger)
        ->setUsername($username)
        ->setPassword($password);
    $client = new Client($options);
    $client->connect();
    $client->send(new Roster);
    $client->send(new Presence);
    $client->send(new Message);
    $client->disconnect();
```

what am i missing?

Comment: does the server have a certificate?

Comment: yes it have @RiggsFolly